# Using select_ and starts_with R

Tags: r, select, dplyr

Why doesn't this code work?

```
mtcars %>% select_("starts_with('d')")

Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : could not find function "starts_with"
```

This is simplified example. I am trying to pass the select_ command to a function.

Comment: Why not `mtcars %>% select(starts_with('d'))`?

Comment: Or maybe `mtcars %>% select_(~starts_with('d'))` , if you really want to use `select_` with the underscore, for whatever reason.

Comment: I'm passing select_ to a function. Bottom example worked. Thank you

Comment: It does with `packageVersion("dplyr")` 0.4.3

Comment: @JoelKanerva Glad to heart that it works. In that case I post my comment as an answer, so that the question can be closed.

Answer (score 4):

The difference between `select()` and `select_()` is their non-stadard / standard evaluation of the argument. If a function like `starts_with()` is used as an argument of `select_()` it should be quoted with a tilde:

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% select_(~starts_with('d'))
```

This yields the same output as the normal use of `select`:

```
identical(mtcars %>% select_(~starts_with('d')), mtcars %>% select(starts_with('d')))
#[1] TRUE
```

For more information see the vignette on non-standard evaluation: `vignette("nse")`.

Comment: t/f: select(arg,...) should be replaced with select_(~arg,...) in every instance that's not on the console? your example seems to contradict this page https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.3/topics/select