# Dplyr select_ and starts_with on multiple values in a variable list

Tags: r, select, dplyr, startswith

I am collecting data from differnt sensors in various locations, data output is something like:

```
df<-data.frame(date=c(2011,2012,2013,2014,2015),"Sensor1 Temp"=c(15,18,15,14,19),"Sensor1 Pressure"=c(1001, 1000, 1002, 1004, 1000),"Sensor1a Temp"=c(15,18,15,14,19),"Sensor2 Temp"=c(15,18,15,14,19),"Sensor2 Pressure"=c(1001, 1000, 1002, 1004, 1000))
```

The problem is (I think) similar to: [Using select_ and starts_with R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38826278/using-select-and-starts-with-r)

I want to search for sensors for example by location so I have a list to search through the dataframe and also include the timestamp. But searching falls apart when I search for more than one sensor (or type of sensor etc). Is there a way of using dplyr (NSE or SE) to achieve this?

```
Findsensor = c("Sensor1") # one value
test <- df %>% select_(.dots = ~starts_with(Findsensor)) # works

Findsensor = c("date", "Sensor1", "Sensor2") # more values
test <- df %>% select_(.dots = ~starts_with(Findsensor)) # doesn't work
```

This is part of a larger pipe (hence using dplyr) and wish to integrate the selecting with Shiny so flexibility is important. The searching could be different locations or sensors or some other variable based on character searching.

Many thanks in advance!
Continued here: [Dplyr select_ and starts_with on multiple values in a variable list part 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45375409/dplyr-select-and-starts-with-on-multiple-values-in-a-variable-list-part-2)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [select columns based on multiple strings with dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29018292/select-columns-based-on-multiple-strings-with-dplyr)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We can use the regex

```
df %>% 
   select(matches(paste(Findsensor, collapse="|")))
```

Comment: Thanks for this and this definitely is perfect for the example. I might update the question to highlight the more subtle variations that this approach might fail on but will use this method for now!

Comment: @BhavShah Could you post as a new question

Comment: Thanks! and yes will post as a new question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45375409/dplyr-select-and-starts-with-on-multiple-values-in-a-variable-list-part-2